# Python 3, Ethereum - how to send ERC20 Tokens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, parity-io

i have some script using to sending Ethers from address to addres. Im using Parity, and Python 3.6. It is using Flask looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
import urllib
import requests
import binascii
from decimal import *
app = Flask(__name__)

def Eth(method,params=[]):
    data = {"method":method,"params":params,"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(ethrpc, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    r = r.text
    response = json.loads(r)
    return(response)
hot = str("XXXXXXX")
@app.route('/')
def index():
    ethnumbers = int(10)**int(18)
    hot = str("XXXXX")
    balance = Eth("eth_getBalance",[hot,'latest'])
    balance = balance["result"]
    balance = int(balance, 16)
    balance = float(balance)
    balance = balance / ethnumbers
    balance = str(balance)
    return render_template('index.html',hot = hot,balance=balance)


@app.route('/send/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def send():
    getcontext().prec = 28
    ethnumbers = Decimal(10)**Decimal(18)
    print(ethnumbers)
    if request.method == "POST":    
        _myaddress = request.form['_myaddress']
        _youraddress = request.form['_youraddress']
        _amount = request.form['_amount']
        _gas = request.form['_gas']
        _gas = hex(int(_gas))
        passy = str("XXXXXXXXX")
        getcontext().prec = 28
        _amount = Decimal(_amount)
        getcontext().prec = 28
        _amount = _amount * ethnumbers
        getcontext().prec = 28
        _amount = int(_amount)
        _amount = hex(_amount)
        r = [{'from':_myaddress,"to":_youraddress,"value":_amount,"gas":_gas,},str("XXXXXXXXXX!")]
        print(r)
        json.dumps(r)
        resultio = Eth("personal_sendTransaction",r)
        try: 
            resultio["result"]
            return render_template('sent.html',resultio=resultio["result"])
        except: KeyError
        return render_template('sent.html',resultio=resultio["error"]["message"])

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')







if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Im pretty sure, that i have to use "data" to do this, but i have no idea how to send via this script ERC20 tokens. Structure of tokens transaction looks like "my address -> token address -> token receiver".

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out http://web3py.readthedocs.io/ to abstract away the json-rpc protocol.

Comment: You can refer the node version. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019666/6521116) of [Send ERC20 token with web3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48180941/6521116).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys it was simpler than it looks like. 
You just have to put:

> contract address

as receiver and make a long "data" field, it represents string as:

```
// method name, its constans in erc20

0xa9059cbb

//receiver address (you have to do it without "0x" because its needed only when
//you have to tell "im using hexadecimal". You did it above, in method field.
//so, receiver address:

5b7b3b499fb69c40c365343cb0dc842fe8c23887

// and fill it with zeros, it have to be lenght 64. So fill rest of address 

0000000000000000000000005b7b3b499fb69c40c365343cb0dc842fe8c23887

// then you need amount, please convert it to hexadecimal, delete "0x" and 
// remember, you need to integer first, so if token has 18 "decimals" it need
// to be amount / 10**18 first!!
//1e27786570c272000 and fill that with zeros, like above:

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e27786570c272000

//just add string, to string, to string, and you have data field: 

0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000005b7b3b499fb69c40c365343cb0dc842fe8c23887000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e27786570c272000
```

Sample transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9c27df8af24e06edb819a8d7a380f548fad637de5edddd6155d15087d1619964

Answer (score 3):

`web3.py` is definitely the way to go. If you want to do it by hand and you just want to call the standard ERC-20 `transfer` method, the `from` address should stay the same, the `to` address should be the token contract, and then the `data` should be the following concatenated together and formatted as hexadecimal:

1. The first 4 bytes of the keccak256 hash of "transfer(address,uint256)", which is the function's signature.
2. The address of the recipient, left-zero-padded to be 32 bytes.
3. The amount to be transferred. (Be sure to take into account the token's decimals... 1 token is often 10**18, but the number of decimal places varies from token to token and can be retrieved by calling the `decimals()` function.) This should also be formatted as a 32-byte number (so left-zero-padded).

`web3.py` would be much easier. :-) Something like:

```
web3.eth.contract(address, abi=standard_token_abi).sendTransaction({
    'from': from_address
}).transfer(to_address, amount)
```

Comment: hmm "standard token abi" you mean that every contract has a unique abi, or maybe i have generate abi from transaction?

Comment: The ABI essentially describes the interface exposed by a contract. ERC20 is a standard for tokens, so all token contracts implement the same basic ABI. You can use that.