# How can I generate smart contracts to send arbitrary ERC20 tokens with Web3j?

Tags: java, android, ethereum, erc20, web3-java

I'm writing an android wallet similar in functionality to MyEtherWallet, and I can't seem to find any example of how to generate a contract using Web3j to send arbitrary ERC20 tokens. Does anyone have a good example of that or do I need to generate a separate contract for each token I'd want to send, and if so how can I do that in java?

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019666/6521116) of [Send ERC20 token with web3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48180941/6521116)