# ERC20 token , transferfrom crashes , what would be the consequences?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

We have created an ERC20 token for TGE/ICO .
In our testing we have found that transferFrom function does not work and crashes
rest all the functions are working properly . the tokens are already deployed on mainnet
what impact will this have apart from user not able to transfer on someone's behalf  ?
Also will this impact later when the token comes on exchange in anyway ? or user is only going to use transfer function?

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019666/6521116) of [Send ERC20 token with web3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48180941/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "crashes"? Are transactions rolled back and the resulting state correct or are tokens lost/irretrievable as a result of using the function?

Either way, as a user I would not want to purchase your token. If one of the ERC20 functions doesn't work properly, I certainly wouldn't have trust that the contract is secure. The impact will be that you will have irate customers who won't want your token. Users will expect to be able to use the `transferFrom` function since you're advertising your token as an ERC20 compliant token. I'd also think that no exchange will accept your token.

Comment: , it crashes means the state is rollback , tokens are not transferred , however they remain with the source account  , this was done purposefully and was realised later that transferFrom is not working .so my question is what is the impact? when does a normal user who has this coins on exchange would invoke transferFrom?   or would exchange check each and every function before listing coins?  or they just look for function declaration ?   any guidance here would be helpful

Comment: It provides the ability (along with `approve`) for a smart contract to initiate a transfer on behalf of the token owner. Each exchange has it’s own verification procees, but none of them will allow one with a non-functioning ERC20 function such as this (at least none I would use)

Comment: approve is working fine , and when you say non-functioning ERC20 function , does each exchange check it all the functions thoroughly?    and i understood use of transferFrom function but when does a normal user use this function?      As transfer function is working fine