# What is the data option of eth_sendTransaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to send ERC20 token using JSON RPC. I am very new in this step and learning. I am using eth_sendTransaction function. What is "value" and "data" option in this case ? Please help

Comment: There is an ethereum stackexchange where you might have better luck asking this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rickjerrity thanks

Comment: You can refer [Send ERC20 token with web3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019666/6521116) to have a good understand.

Answer (score 0):

From https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/29/how-ethereum-transactions-work/:

> The following values are encoded:
>
> - **recipient** – The account address to which the transaction is being sent.
> - **value** – The amount of ether to transfer from the sender to the recipient. This amount may be zero.
> - **data** – Optional arbitrary binary data. During contract deployment, this is where the contract’s bytecode is sent. When calling a function on a contract, this specifies which function should be called and with what arguments. For simple transfers of ether, the data portion of the transaction is typically omitted.
> - **gas limit** – The maximum amount of gas that can be consumed by the transaction.
> - **gas price** – The amount the sender will pay for each unit of gas.
> - **nonce** – A sequence number called a “nonce”. The sequence number is per sender and must match the next available sequence number exactly.
> - **signature** – Data that identifies and authenticates the transaction’s sender.

Comment: where to know/set that ethereum transaction or erc20 token transaction ?

Comment: That question is unrelated. Please ask it separately (on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send ERC20 tokens via RPC calls, you need to call the `transfer` function of the token contract with correct parameters.

Since ERC20 is not a well-defined standard, but rather an *interface* I would not recommend doing that blindly, you would have to study the contract source first to make sure it's possible.

To answer your question on a higher level:

- `value` is the amount of Ether transferred (in Wei) and should be `0` because you do not want to transfer any ETH.
- `data` is the hex-encoded execution of the ERC20 `transfer`, e.g., the method name called, and it's parameters.

I highly recommend using a wallet that supports ERC20 tokens, such as MyCrypto or Parity, but that is probably not what you are asking for :)

*Note, I work for Parity.*