# Can't able to call web3 api(getTransactionReceipt) wia npm

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

For access erc20 token api calling, I have followed the stack ticket ([Send ERC20 token with web3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180941/send-erc20-token-with-web3))

And tried to call a test method to fetch the transaction details with the below code in nodejs,

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:5000/'))

var receipt =  web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x3265c1461d3f167c756fbc062ae3a2dc279b44a9c3ca2194271d4251cd0c1655')
```

But as in result I got the error : `errors.InvalidResponse(request.responseText);Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined`

I have also tried the 'geth' for RPC but cant't work for me as expected;Please let me know some way to deal with this.